# UIPopoverController and UIImagePickerController on iPad in ARC environment

Tags: ipad, crash, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to use camera on iPad and I have to use UIPopoverController on iPad for this. I have been getting following error no matter UIPopoverController declared strong!

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.'
```

Following is my code. Could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong? I have went through most of related questions on SO but most of them says declare UIPopoverController strong that I am already doing!

```
#import "ImagePickerController.h"

@interface ImagePickerController()
    @property(nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
@end

@implementation ImagePickerController

@synthesize imageName;
@synthesize popoverController;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

#pragma mark - UIImagePickerController Delegate

-(void) captureImageFromCamera:(UIViewController*)view
{

        UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
        self.popoverController.delegate = self;
        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:view.view.bounds inView:view.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - UIPopoverController Delegate

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{

}

- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't resolve my issue but [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_4_iPad_Camera_and_UIImagePickerController_Application_%28Xcode_4%29) worked like a charm on iOS 5 as well. Thanks to http://www.techotopia.com!

Answer (score 1):

The PopoverController owns the ImagePicker in this case so the problem is (probably) that you are dismissing the ImagePicker rather the container PopoverController.

Where you call

`[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

use

`[self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];`

Theres no need to explicitly dismiss the ImagePicker

Comment: It needs the animated in there: `[self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];`

Comment: Sure.. probably something new since 2012.  Thanks though cause this was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController;`

Synthesize it   `@synthesize imagePickerController;`

and change `imagePickerController` the method `captureImageFromCamera` like this:

```
imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

Comment: I tried that. Didn't make any difference. The problem is with UIPopoverController which is strong so when I add UIImagePickerController to it as content, ARC won't release UIImagePickerController anyway but not sure why UIPopoverController getting released!!

Comment: I tried to presentPopoverFromRect like you did and got your error. But when you do imagePickerController as global variable or as property everything works as expected.